# Firestore Collection: Compound Query fails with AngularFire2 v5.rc6

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm getting this error on a very similar query to the one displayed on AngularFire2 documents for collection query:

```
this.shops$ = this.afs.collection<IShop>('shops', ref => {
  let query: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.firestore.Query = ref;
```

**Error (on `ref =>`):**

```
Argument of type '(ref: CollectionReference) => CollectionReference | Query' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryFn'.
  Type 'CollectionReference | Query' is not assignable to type 'Query'.
    Type 'CollectionReference' is not assignable to type 'Query'.
      Types of property 'firestore' are incompatible.
        Type 'Firestore' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseFirestore'.
          Property 'enableNetwork' is missing in type 'Firestore'.
```

This happens on AngularFire2: `5.0.0-rc.6` and firebase: `4.9.1` and does NOT happen on AngularFire2: `5.0.0-rc.4` and firebase: `4.9.1` setup.

Is there a change I am not aware which I have to do for app setup with latest version?

Comment: there is a new update out 4.10.1 - didnt solve it for me though. am having the same issue, AngularFire2: 5.0.0-rc.6 firebase: 4.9.1 and AngularFire2: 5.0.0-rc.6 / firebase: 4.10.1. same error on query ref

Comment: What I see is at 4.8.0 and after 4.8.2 there were some typing definition changes on Firebase side, but it was just before that moment AngularFire 5.rc-6 was released. Bad communication (or no communication) maybe between teams, even worse is Google devs constant disregard of semantic versioning rules (Angular team did it often last year as well) causes these type of nuisance.

Answer (score 2):

Just found an answer via [github](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1467) (all credit goes to [jeremyben](https://github.com/jeremyben))

Use types added with recent firebase updates :

import { Query } from '@firebase/firestore-types'

Then cast your reference to a query :

let query: Query = ref;

Comment: Yes I've seen that one too, though there seems to have other type miss-match situations still needs fixing it seems.